# Is it possible to access a UNC path from an Azure webjob?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to access a unc path from Azure webjob which is in C#. Is it possible to connect to shared path which is in local network?

Comment: Since azure webjobs are running in the cloud, you don't have access to the local network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment is right, azure webjobs cannot access local path.

You can consider use [azure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/), like azure blob / azure files for the solution. Or FTP server which can be public accessed.